# Wildfly Swarm error connecting Postgres datasource on Docker container

Tags: java, jpa, docker, wildfly, microservices

I am trying to build a simple rest service using Wildfly Swarm, Docker and PostgreSQL as database.

The application works well on localhost (without docker).

I am having problems to connect the database using a data source on docker infrastructure

This is my `docker.compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

  web:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    build: ./db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

My Web `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM fabric8/java-jboss-openjdk8-jdk:1.2.3

ENV AB_OFF true

ADD megasindico-billing-api-swarm.jar /opt/megasindico-billing-api-swarm.jar

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/megasindico-billing-api-swarm.jar"]
```

PostgreSQL `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM postgres:9.4-alpine

ENV POSTGRES_USER=admin
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
```

`project-defaults.yml` is where is configure my DataSource:

```
swarm:
  datasources:
    data-sources:
      ### [datasource]
      megasindico-billing-ds:
        driver-name: postgresql
        connection-url: jdbc:postgresql://db/postgres
        user-name: admin
        password: admin
```

And heres how the `persistence.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="megasindico-billing-ds" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files" value="scripts/reset.sql"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

The app is built using `mvn clean package` command.

To build the images I use a `build.sh` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Copy jar file to this directory
cp ../target/megasindico-billing-api-swarm.jar megasindico-billing-api-swarm.jar

# Build Docker image
docker-compose build

# Remove temp file
rm -rf megasindico-billing-api-swarm.jar
```

After that I execute `docker-compose up` command to get images running.

The errors I get are these:
[image: error part 1]

[image: error part 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the Docker entry point, i.e.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/megasindico-billing-api-swarm.jar", "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"]
```

And please copy and paste the text of the errors instead of posting screen shots.  No one in the future searching for a similar issue will be able to find it as it's a screen shot.

Comment: Dude, wish I could pay u a beer